# Multiple file upload in nested Rails 4 model not working with strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

Well I have spent my required 24 hours trying to figure this out without luck.

I have a very simple setup using simple_form and a nested model with accepts_nested_attributes_for:

```
= f.simple_fields_for :images, Image.new do |fi|
 %label.file
   = fi.input_field :image, as: :file, multiple: true
   %span.file-custom
```

Nothing tricky there.  Form displays and I can select multiple files.  When I try to submit, however, BAM.  This is Rails 4.2.  It's strong parameters.  Here is what I have tried for `def material_params`

```
params.require(:material).permit(:name, :url, :description, :subject_id, :universal_id, :universal_id_type, :short_description, :expires_on, :submitter_id, site_ids: [], instructor_ids: [], instructors_attributes: [:name]).permit(images_attributes: [:image, :_destroy, :id])


params.require(:material).permit(:name, :url, :description, :subject_id, :universal_id, :universal_id_type, :short_description, :expires_on, :submitter_id, site_ids: [], instructor_ids: [], instructors_attributes: [:name]).permit({images_attributes: [:image, :_destroy, :id]})

params.require(:material).permit(:name, :url, :description, :subject_id, :universal_id, :universal_id_type, :short_description, :expires_on, :submitter_id, site_ids: [], instructor_ids: [], instructors_attributes: [:name]).permit({images_attributes: [:image, :_destroy, :id]}).tap do |whitelisted|
  whitelisted[:images_attributes] = params[:material][:images_attributes]
end

params.require(:material).permit(:name, :url, :description, :subject_id, :universal_id, :universal_id_type, :short_description, :expires_on, :submitter_id, site_ids: [], instructor_ids: [], instructors_attributes: [:name]).permit(:images_attributes).tap do |whitelisted|
  whitelisted[:images_attributes] = params[:material][:images_attributes]
end 

params.require(:material).permit(:name, :url, :description, :subject_id, :universal_id, :universal_id_type, :short_description, :expires_on, :submitter_id, site_ids: [], instructor_ids: [], instructors_attributes: [:name]).permit(images_attributes: [:image, :_destroy, :id]).tap do |whitelisted|
  whitelisted[:images_attributes] = params[:material][:images_attributes]
end
```

and here is a sample of the POST:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
     "_method"=>"patch",
     "authenticity_token"=>"mWI5pvoejIQhLKHBmr0/XHKYonhR67GKAvm4j4PYkLRqC6VnmmycEafqnwOXqJdf/n9Mk65EfCnSzbMiHPqv0A==",
     "material"=>{"submitter_id"=>"1",
     "name"=>"Official Guide to the ACT",
     "url"=>"http://amazon.com/act",
     "short_description"=>"",
     "expires_on"=>"2015-12-16",
     "description"=>"",
     "universal_id"=>"",
     "universal_id_type"=>"ISBN",
     "instructor_ids"=>["",
     "1",
     "3"],
     "images_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"_destroy"=>"0",
     "id"=>"5"},
     "1"=>{"image"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007ff01e6481e0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/dw/pz_hxz2x43gdqnphs6h6skr40000gn/T/RackMultipart20151216-86036-18d4wsp.jpg>,
     @original_filename="il_570xN.760452533_rc6v.jpg",
     @content_type="image/jpeg",
     @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"material[images_attributes][1][image][]\"; filename=\"il_570xN.760452533_rc6v.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">,
     #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007ff01e6481b8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/dw/pz_hxz2x43gdqnphs6h6skr40000gn/T/RackMultipart20151216-86036-80v4nh.jpg>,
     @original_filename="imgres.jpg",
     @content_type="image/jpeg",
     @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"material[images_attributes][1][image][]\"; filename=\"imgres.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">]}},
     "instructors_attributes"=>{"2"=>{"name"=>""}},
     "site_ids"=>["",
     "1"]},
     "commit"=>"Update Material",
     "id"=>"official-guide-to-the-act"}
```

and I ALWAYS get:

```
found unpermitted parameter: images_attributes
```

Comment: Have you tried including images_attributes as a parameter in the materials hash? for example: params.require(:material).permit(:name, :url, :description, :subject_id, :universal_id, :universal_id_type, :short_description, :expires_on, :submitter_id, images_attributes: [:image, :_destroy, :id], site_ids: [], instructor_ids: [], instructors_attributes: [:name])

Comment: Yes.  All of the ones above where I have the second permit were also tried with the first permit.